# iOS: calculating the remainder of a division for a long number

Tags: ios

I have got an NSString * with for example the following numbers @"182316110006010135232100" and i need to do a calculation with this complete value. I have tried multiple types of number systems on iOS SDK for example Int, Float, etc. But because of the amount of bits it changes the number when i change the StringValue to for example an IntValue.
I need to do the following sum with this complete value: mod(digit, 97);

I have checked with for as far i know the longest type of number in Objective-C Long Long:

```
long long digit = [(NSString *)shouldBechecksum longLongValue];
```

And need to do the following calculation:

```
mod(digit, 97);
```

Now i get strange results because it does the sum with max version of the number. I need it to do this sum:

```
mod(182316110006010135232100, 97);
```

How can i do this calculation correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you could use NSDecimalNumber -- it supports 38 decimal digits.  You'd probably have to do `mod` the long way -- divide/multipy/subtract.

Comment: Can anyone help me with the mod part then?

Comment: I just did.  Divide, multiply, and subtract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSDecimalNumber class for precision up to 38 digits. To obtain the mod, just use this formula with the corresponding NSDecimalNumber methods you'll find explained in the documentation.

```
Mod = digit - int(digit/97)
```

This is because NSDecimalNumber can only do the basic operations, you have to obtain the mod as we did in school.

From Apple documentation:

NSDecimalNumber, an immutable subclass of NSNumber, provides an object-oriented wrapper for doing base-10 arithmetic. An instance can represent any number that can be expressed as mantissa x 10^exponent where mantissa is a decimal integer up to 38 digits long, and exponent is an integer from –128 through 127.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Thanks!

```
NSDecimalNumber *bigDecimal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:shouldBechecksum];
NSDecimalNumber *divisor = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:97] decimalValue]];
NSDecimalNumber *quotient = [bigDecimal decimalNumberByDividingBy:divisor withBehavior:[NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundDown scale:0 raiseOnExactness:NO raiseOnOverflow:NO raiseOnUnderflow:NO raiseOnDivideByZero:NO]];

NSDecimalNumber *subtractAmount = [quotient decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:divisor];

NSDecimalNumber *remainder = [bigDecimal decimalNumberBySubtracting:subtractAmount];
int checkSum = 98 - [remainder intValue];
```

Comment: Why you use checksum = 98-remainder?

Comment: Ok I was just curiuos because 98 is 97+1.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a little test with the following code snippet:

```
NSString *digitStr = @"182316110006010135232100";

long long digit = [(NSString *)digitStr longLongValue];

short checksum = digit % 97;

NSLog(@"%@, %lli, %lli, %i", digitStr, LONG_LONG_MAX, digit, checksum);
```

The result was:

```
182316110006010135232100, 9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775807, 78
```

This means that your value passes the LONG_LONG_MAX value. So, your problem is not feasible this way.

Remark: apparently Objective C puts the value closest to your number in the variabel digit, being LONG_LONG_MAX.

I guess you will have to find some kind of solution for even longer numbers to do what you want to do. Maybe NSDecimalNumber.

Kind regards,
PF